# Report generation from XML

Tags: xml, reporting-services, report

I have developed a software that currently dumps data into an excel file (into various categorized sheets). The excel file is a copy of a predefined template that I programmatically copy and then dump the data in.

The pre-defined template file contains additional sheets that link and organize the data from the sheets with data. This gives me an incredibly flexible system to change the format, look or design of the final reports without touching the program.

I want to do a similar thing but avoid using Excel. Can anyone suggest me an alternative?